# User is not getting redirected until page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a login page, in which I have written JQuery code to make an ajax post request which in turn calls another php script to validate the user credentials. If the credentials are correct, user will be redirected to the home page in the php script itself. But when the user gives his credentials, and clicks login he isnt getting redirected until page is reloaded. This is the strange issue I am facing. Please help me resolve it.

Here is my JQuery code:

```
<script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                $('#loginButton').click(function ()
                {

                    var username = $("#inputUsername").val();             
                    var password = $("#inputPassword").val();
                    var dataString = 'inputUsername=' + username + '&inputPassword=' + password;
                    if ($.trim(username).length > 0 && $.trim(password).length > 0)
                    {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "ajaxLogin.php",
                            data: dataString,
                            cache: false,
                            beforeSend: function () {
                                $("#loginButton").val('Connecting...');
                            },

                        });
                    }
                    return false;
                });

            });
</script>
```

This is html login form

```
<form>
                    <div class="form-group center-block">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUsername" placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-login center-block" id="loginButton">Login</button>
                    <div id="error"></div>
               </form>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
include("db.php");
session_start();
$username=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['inputUsername']); 
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['inputPassword']); 
$result=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT user_id FROM user_info WHERE username='".$username."' and password='".$password."'");
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
// If result matched $username and $password, table row  must be 1 row
if($count==1)
{
$_SESSION['login_user']=$row['user_id']; //Storing user session value.
header('Location: home.html');
} 
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: your PHP code is called from the AJAX request, so the redirect is sent to that reply, not to the page itself

Comment: also, you are storing plain passwords in the db, see this guide: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Comment: ...and what if someone types an `&` in the user or password field? Your query string will break. Use `$.post` and pass an array to the second parameter

Comment: Why are you using Ajax when you need to relocate? Why not just send your data via PHP via the form action and include a header location at the end of the script?

Comment: Depending on the type of user, the re-directed page will be different. Hence I am redirecting through php script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Ajax** request on **PHP** when terminate that you use of `echo` in php section, and you will be use `exit()` method after `echo` to cancel continue page.

My opinion for you is, you use a `echo` command and `exit()` and use **Success method** in Ajax to **validate `echo` value** and if validate is true **redirect with JavaScript.**

```
<script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#loginButton').click(function ()
            {

                var username = $("#inputUsername").val();             
                var password = $("#inputPassword").val();
                var dataString = 'inputUsername=' + username + '&inputPassword=' + password;
                if ($.trim(username).length > 0 && $.trim(password).length > 0)
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "ajaxLogin.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (data)
                            {
                                if (data == 1) {
                                    window.location = "home.html";
                            }
                        beforeSend: function () {
                            $("#loginButton").val('Connecting...');
                        },

                    });
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            });

        });
```

You will be this code in php if your validate is TRUE :

```
echo 1;
exit();
```

echo 1, return 1 to data in Success method .

Answer (score 1):

Do your page redirect in the $.ajax success handler, not on the php side.\

Comment: Depending on the type of user, the page redirected will be different. Hence I am redirecting through php